# SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'XXX/check?wsdl' : failed to load external entity "XXX/check?wsdl'"

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl

I have done SoapServer using Zend framework Symfony. I am able to generate wsdl file both in browser and in Terminal (Ubuntu). But I am getting

> SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'XXX/check?wsdl' :
>   failed to load external entity "XXX/check?wsdl'"

in SoapClient program on the line :

```
$client = new SoapClient("http://xxx/check?wsdl");
```

Am'I doing any wrong ?

Comment: What happens if you open the url in a browser? Does it show a WSDL or something else?

Comment: it will display wsdl

Comment: you can try to use `libxml_disable_entity_loader(false);` before creating the SoapServer or SoapClient. The error can appear on both and I was able to fix them with this workaround